# Benchgraph httpref - cannot execute binary file

Tags: ubuntu, benchmark, httperf

I am trying to make graph of an httperf file with benchgraph (http://www.uprb.edu/profesor/jsola/benchgraph/)

When I run the command: `benchgraph --ff txt --fn httperf --exporter httperf`
I get

```
bash: /usr/local/sbin/benchgraph: cannot execute binary file
```

Never been into that error, what can be wrong ?